# Kotlin. How to execute code on a button up event

Tags: kotlin, onkeyup

Kotlin. How to execute code on a button up event

I'm new to android. How do you handle a button up event?

I can get a onclicklistener working,but need to execute code when button released

```
btnDownFast.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to override `View.OnTouchListener` callback method instead and you also take care of `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`

```
btnDownFast.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            when (event?.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> //Do Something
            }

            return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
        }
    })
```